# Launcher does not appear on my desktop and applications frequently freeze

Tags: launcher, freeze

I am getting generally unacceptable performance from my computer. I have two types of problems:

1. Sometimes the Launcher does not appear on my desktop.
2. The web browser and other applications frequently freeze, and I am unable to even exit from them.

What should I do?

Comment: which software is not working properly?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Applications freezing and no Launcher could both be caused by trying to install Ubuntu on a computer that does not meet the minimal system requirements for it. Ubuntu publishes Release Notes for each official Ubuntu derivative that it releases, which can be easily found by searching for something like "Ubuntu 13.10 release notes" for your particular version. In the release notes you will find the minimal system requirements for your *buntu version.

If you want to try a more lightweight Ubuntu derivative there is Xubuntu which requires 512MB RAM and Lubuntu which only requires 128MB RAM.

Also to check if your problem is caused by a graphics driver issue you can search the Dash for *Additional Drivers* and click the Additional Drivers icon to open the Additional Drivers window where you will be able to see if there is a Recommended graphics card driver that is available to be installed.